# Calculate CIR with multibandread Matlab

Tags: matlab, rgb, infrared

I'm trying to calculate the CIR(standard color-infrared) of an Image using the function multibandread but give me an error.
I'm trying this tutorial of mathworks:
[Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/finding-vegetation-in-a-multispectral-image.html?refresh=true)

The image is 500x500x3 uint8. This is my code:

```
G = imread ('nir.tif');
if size(G,3) == 4  %alpha
G = G(:,:,1:3);  %strip alpha
end
CIR = multibandread(G, [500, 500, 4], 'uint8=>uint8',...
                128, 'bil', 'ieee-le', {'Band','Direct',[4 3 2]});
figure
imshow(CIR);
```

This is the error: `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`

Comment: Have you tried Oguzhan's proposal?

Comment: I tried, but didnt work. Same error

Comment: Can you please send as your example picture?

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention in which line the error occurs but it seems like there is a problem about ***size*** parameter of `multibandread` function.

First, you have limited number of bands of the image to 3, then tried to read 4 bands from image.

Your problem may be solved with following change:

```
CIR = multibandread(G, [500, 500, 3], 'uint8=>uint8',...
                128, 'bil', 'ieee-le', {'Band','Direct',[3 2 1]});
```

Moreover, the first parameter of `multibandread`, ***filename***, should be in string, not a matrix.